# Why should I create a new object reference to do a function call opposed to using an existing one?

Tags: java, class, subclass

My variable `program` is a object with a list of `ByteCode` subclass objects which I want to execute using an abstract method named `execute()`. The `getNextCode()` gets the next `ByteCode` object in that list.

My question is, why would I want to create a new instance of `ByteCode` just to call the `execute()` method instead of just referencing the instance in the list and calling the execute method the way the second code box does? Is there a difference? Is it for some reason safer to create a new instance? Does it have something to do with the process of dynamic binding here?

highlighting the two statements

```
program.getNextCode(pc).execute(this);

 ByteCode code = program.getNextCode(pc); 
 code.execute(this);
```

```
  public void executeProgram() { 
          runStack = new RunTimeStack(); 
          returnAddrs = new Stack(); 
          isRunning = true;
          pc = 0;

           while (isRunning) {
            ByteCode code = program.getNextCode(pc); 
            code.execute(this);
```

```
   public void executeProgram(){

        runStack = new RunTimeStack();
        returnAddrs = new Stack();
        isRunning = true;
        pc = 0;

        while(isRunning){
        program.getNextCode(pc).execute(this);
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you don't see `new` anywhere, no **new** instances are created; references are merely reassigned. As to whether you want to assign a named variable and then use that or simply dereference in a chain is a matter of readability - generally speaking, long dereference chains are discouraged.

Comment: sorry my mistake i will fix the title. I am new to java but I understand now whats going on in that statement

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code:

```
 ByteCode code = program.getNextCode(pc);
```

You are not creating a new ByteCode instance, you are just **referencing** the **instance** that `program.getNextCode(pc`) returns.

Comment: so wouldnt that make the two statements essentially the same?

Comment: @localplutonium identical, yes. Once the compiler is done with then, most likely exactly identical.

Comment: @localplutonium is right. Maybe sometimes you want to do this type of things to improve code reading.

Comment: @JuanMarcosArmella , that makes sense. Im glad theres no difference as I noticed.